# TestSuite with GoogleTest Framework

Tags: c++, googletest

I am reading a book for unit testing, titled "Unit Test Frameworks", and I have learned that a simple unit testing architecture should have following classes:

1. TestCase
2. TestFixture
3. TestSuite
4. TestResult
5. TestRunning

How can I create a TestSuite with GoogleTest?

The only explanation I found is to use different Fixture class names, and then filter them. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution, like that in CppUnit or jUnit with a proper Suite class.

Comment: Search for projects or examples using that test framework. Most of those classes are provided by the test framework, not by you!

Comment: Ulrich that's just my point,  I have looked for it, in google advance tutorial and surfing the net but there is no trace, pls can you provide some examples

Comment: @MaxMarcucci : I think your question is sharp and that googletest actually lacks the ability to create TestSuite. The filter solution for running only a subset of test maching or not matching some pattern is a workaround that force as well the test naming.